# C++ adds an extra number to an int when subtracting it

Tags: c++, int, subtraction

I am working on an ASCII game in C++. The player moves around avoiding obstacles ('X's). The player has health and loses it when hitting an obstacle. I declared the health as an int and set to 100:

```
int health = 100;
```

And then I made a switch case detecting the collision. 
Then I typed:

```
health--;
```

And ran the program. I ran into an obstacle and it lowered the health but added an extra number (For example, instead of saying 99, it said 999).
I tried debugging but found nothing. What am I doing wrong? Here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define FPS 100

using namespace std;

char Map[21][33] =
{
    "##############################",
    "#@                           #",
    "#                            #",
    "#                            #",
    "#                            #",
    "#                            #",
    "#                            #",
    "#                            #",
    "#                            #",
    "#                            #",
    "#                            #",
    "#                            #",
    "#                            #",
    "#                            #",
    "#                            #",
    "#                            #",
    "#                            #",
    "#                            #",
    "#                           !#",
    "##############################",


};

int x = 1;
int y = 1;
int choice;
int level = 1;
int health = 100;
int lives = 5;
int score;

void clearScreen()
{
    short posX = 0;
    short posY = 0;
    COORD coord = {posX,posY};
    SetConsoleCursorPosition(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), coord);
}

void clearMoney()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 33; j++)
        {
            switch(Map[i][j])
            {
            case '$':
            {
                Map[i][j] = ' ';
            }
            }
        }
    }
}

void setupMoney()
{
    clearMoney();
    for(int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 33; j++)
        {
            switch(Map[i][j])
            {
            case ' ':
            {
                choice = rand() % 30 + 1;
                switch(choice)
                {
                case 2:
                {
                    Map[i][j] = '$';
                }
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }
}

void clearObstacles()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 33; j++)
        {
            switch(Map[i][j])
            {
            case 'X':
            {
                Map[i][j] = ' ';
            }
            }
        }
    }
}

void setupObstacles()
{
    clearObstacles();
    for(int i = 0; i < 21; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 33; j++)
        {
            switch(Map[i][j])
            {
            case ' ':
            {
                choice = rand() % 15 + 1;
                switch(choice)
                {
                case 2:
                {
                    Map[i][j] = 'X';
                }
                }
            }
            }
        }
    }
}

void showMap()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < 33; j++)
        {
            printf("%c", Map[i][j]);
        }
        putchar('\n');
    }
}

void convertToAscii()
{
    for(int g = 0; g < 20; g++)
    {
        for(int h = 0; h < 30; h++)
        {
            switch(Map[g][h])
            {
            case '#':
            {
                Map[g][h] = 219;
                break;
            }
            case '@':
            {
                Map[g][h] = 254;
                break;
            }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    printf("Loading...");
    convertToAscii();
    setupObstacles();
    setupMoney();
    system("cls");
    for( ; ; )
    {
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP))
        {
            switch(Map[y-1][x])
            {
            case ' ':
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < rand() % 5 + 2; i++)
                {
                    switch(Map[y-1][x])
                    {
                    case ' ':
                    {
                        y--;
                        Map[y][x] = 254;
                        Map[y+1][x] = ' ';
                        showMap();
                        clearScreen();
                        Sleep(FPS);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 'X':
                    {
                        health--;
                        break;
                    }
                    case '!':
                    {
                        Map[y][x] = ' ';
                        x = 1;
                        y = 1;
                        Map[y][x] = 254;
                        setupObstacles();
                        setupMoney();
                        level++;
                        break;
                    }
                    case '$':
                    {
                        score += 50;
                        y--;
                        Map[y][x] = 254;
                        Map[y+1][x] = ' ';
                        showMap();
                        clearScreen();
                    }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            case 'X':
            {
                health--;
                break;
            }
            case '!':
            {
                Map[y][x] = ' ';
                x = 1;
                y = 1;
                Map[y][x] = 254;
                setupObstacles();
                setupMoney();
                break;
            }
            case '$':
            {
                score += 50;
                y--;
                Map[y][x] = 254;
                Map[y+1][x] = ' ';
            }
            }
        }
        else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_DOWN))
        {
            switch(Map[y+1][x])
            {
            case ' ':
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < rand() % 5 + 2; i++)
                {
                    switch(Map[y+1][x])
                    {
                    case ' ':
                    {
                        y++;
                        Map[y][x] = 254;
                        Map[y-1][x] = ' ';
                        showMap();
                        clearScreen();
                        Sleep(FPS);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 'X':
                    {
                        health--;
                        break;
                    }
                    case '!':
                    {
                        Map[y][x] = ' ';
                        x = 1;
                        y = 1;
                        Map[y][x] = 254;
                        setupObstacles();
                        setupMoney();
                        level++;
                        break;
                    }
                    case '$':
                    {
                        score += 50;
                        y++;
                        Map[y][x] = 254;
                        Map[y-1][x] = ' ';
                        showMap();
                        clearScreen();
                    }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            case 'X':
            {
                health--;
                break;
            }
            case '!':
            {
                Map[y][x] = ' ';
                x = 1;
                y = 1;
                Map[y][x] = 254;
                setupObstacles();
                setupMoney();
                break;
            }
            case '$':
            {
                score += 50;
                y++;
                Map[y][x] = 254;
                Map[y-1][x] = ' ';
            }
            }
        }
        else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_LEFT))
        {
            switch(Map[y][x-1])
            {
            case ' ':
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < rand() % 5 + 2; i++)
                {
                    switch(Map[y][x-1])
                    {
                    case ' ':
                    {
                        x--;
                        Map[y][x] = 254;
                        Map[y][x+1] = ' ';
                        showMap();
                        clearScreen();
                        Sleep(FPS);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 'X':
                    {
                        health--;
                        break;
                    }
                    case '!':
                    {
                        Map[y][x] = ' ';
                        x = 1;
                        y = 1;
                        Map[y][x] = 254;
                        setupObstacles();
                        setupMoney();
                        level++;
                        break;
                    }
                    case '$':
                    {
                        score += 50;
                        x--;
                        Map[y][x] = 254;
                        Map[y][x+1] = ' ';
                        showMap();
                    }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            case 'X':
            {
                health--;
                break;
            }
            case '!':
            {
                Map[y][x] = ' ';
                x = 1;
                y = 1;
                Map[y][x] = 254;
                setupObstacles();
                setupMoney();
                level++;
                break;
            }
            case '$':
            {
                score += 50;
                x--;
                Map[y][x] = 254;
                Map[y][x+1] = ' ';
            }
            }
        }
        else if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_RIGHT))
        {
            switch(Map[y][x+1])
            {
            case ' ':
            {
                for(int i = 0; i < rand() % 5 + 2; i++)
                {
                    switch(Map[y][x+1])
                    {
                    case ' ':
                    {
                        x++;
                        Map[y][x] = 254;
                        Map[y][x-1] = ' ';
                        showMap();
                        clearScreen();
                        Sleep(FPS);
                        break;
                    }
                    case 'X':
                    {
                        health--;
                        break;
                    }
                    case '!':
                    {
                        Map[y][x] = ' ';
                        x = 1;
                        y = 1;
                        Map[y][x] = 254;
                        setupObstacles();
                        setupMoney();
                        level++;
                        break;
                    }
                    case '$':
                    {
                        score += 50;
                        x++;
                        Map[y][x] = 254;
                        Map[y][x-1] = ' ';
                        showMap();
                        clearScreen();
                    }
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
            case 'X':
            {
                health--;
                break;
            }
            case '!':
            {
                Map[y][x] = ' ';
                x = 1;
                y = 1;
                Map[y][x] = 254;
                setupObstacles();
                setupMoney();
                level++;
                break;
            }
            case '$':
            {
                score += 50;
                x++;
                Map[y][x] = 254;
                Map[y][x-1] = ' ';
            }
            }
        }
        showMap();
        putchar('\n');
        printf("Health: %i", health);
        putchar('\n');
        printf("Lives: ", lives);
        putchar('\n');
        printf("Score: %i", score);
        putchar('\n');
        printf("Level: %i", level);
        Sleep(FPS);
        clearScreen();
        continue;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's probably the 9 from the previous screen.   you're never actually clearing the screen

Comment: I don't know what's the problem about `health`. But in general: 1.: Please, use a debugger and try to find out by yourself. (You seem to work on Windows. VS has a really nice visual debugger - the best I know.) 2.: You have a lot of code duplication (with less variation) which could be easily moved to a function. This makes code hard to read (and to debug by eyes).

Comment: Why are people voting to close?  The question seems to include all necessary code, a specific question and the current behavior.

Answer (score 2):

I can't run your program, but from what I can see you're never actually clearing the screen, you're just writing on top of older data, but since you're not writing out entire lines, any old data that may still be on the screen doesn't magically disappear unless you overwrite it.

Put some spaces after the %i and I bet your problem goes away.  Try this instead:

```
    printf("Health: %i         ", health);
```

You would want to do this kind of thing on every line where it doesn't always write out the same number of columns.

Also, why don't you put the newline in the `printf` instead of in a subsequent  `putchar`?

```
    printf("Health: %i         \n", health);
```

Comment: If this was not the error, then it would at least exclude this as possible reason.